# how to remove selected jtree from several jtrees by right clicking on

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtree, jdom-2

In my GUI I have  to load several XML files according to JTree structure one by one, If I want to edit or remove a complete JTree or value by right clicking on, how can I do that efficiently? any clue?

I process xml file to jtree as below,

```
        /* Tree implementation. */
    xmlTree = new JTree();
    xmlTree.setRootVisible(false);      
    xmlTree.setEditable(true);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(xmlTree);        
    frame.getContentPane().add("Center", scrollPane);
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
             tn = processElement(xmlDoc.getRootElement());
         ((DefaultTreeModel) xmlTree.getModel()).setRoot(tn);
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
// Open XMl file into the GUI.
private DefaultMutableTreeNode processElement(Element el) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(el.getName());
    String text = el.getTextNormalize();
    if ((text != null) && (!text.equals(""))) {
        node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(text));
    }
    processAttributes(el, node);
    Iterator<Element> children = el.getChildren().iterator();
    while (children.hasNext()) {
        Element next = (Element) children.next();
        node.add(processElement(next));
    } // End of while loop.
    return node;
} // End of method.


// Processing Element attributes.
private void processAttributes(Element el, DefaultMutableTreeNode dmtn) {
    Iterator<Attribute> atts = el.getAttributes().iterator();
    while (atts.hasNext()) {
        Attribute att = (Attribute) atts.next();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode attNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("@" + att.getName());
        attNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(att.getValue()));
        dmtn.add(attNode);
    } // End of while loop.
} // End of method.
```

Comment: Are all the XML structures in the same `JTree` or are they laied out in individual `JTree`s?

Comment: Individual JTrees, if I have 3 XMLs then I have to create 3 JTrees in GUI

Comment: I'd start by taking a look at [JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu%28javax.swing.JPopupMenu%29)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, if I do need to display several jtrees in GUI what is the good method?

Comment: I doesn't really matter.  I'd use `setComponentPopupMenu` and supply the popup menu you need (with the actions you want).  That's simplest method I can think of to provide right click functionality.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, also I want to edit XML file in the GUI/JTree and save them into a local location.